# deploy an upgradable contract using artifacts on hardhat

Tags: javascript, testing, ethereum, smartcontracts, hardhat

To deploy a contract from an artifact on hardhat (for testing purposes) I can get the contract artifact json file and put it in the repo and then do it like this:

```
import XTokenWrapperArtifact from './helpers/artifactsForTesting/XTokenWrapper.json';
const XTokenWrapperFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(
        XTokenWrapperArtifact.abi,
        XTokenWrapperArtifact.bytecode,
        deployer,
      );
      xTokenWrapperContract = await XTokenWrapperFactory.deploy();
      await xTokenWrapperContract.deployed();
```

So I can call the contract using await xTokenWrapperContract.method()

When I have an upgradable contract I try to do the same thing but it is not working:

```
import PermissionManagerArtifact from './helpers/artifactsForTesting/PermissionManager.json';
const PermissionManagerFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(
        PermissionManagerArtifact.abi,
        PermissionManagerArtifact.bytecode,
        deployer,
      );
permissionManagerContract = await upgrades.deployProxy(PermissionManagerFactory, []);
await permissionManagerContract.deployed();
```

I get on the tests this error:

Error: The requested contract was not found. Make sure the source code is available for compilation

Does anybody know how to deploy an upgradable contract from an artifact ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, i'm facing the same error in a deploy with a proxy, did you ever solve it? Thanks

Comment: @refex The plugin requires the source code locally, so an artifact will not do the trick
I just copied the whole contract into my repo